# How to make and use sorted list of objects (containing 2 integers, list should be sorted by one of them)

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I've seen in visual studio (c#) something like SortedList. However, I don't know how does it work and how to use it. I want to use SortedList because I hope it has got fastest access time than a normal list. Unfortunately, I can't use array. I'd be glad to see some simple example.

edit:
Let's say there's an object class:

```
class Point
{
public Point(int a, int b) {x = a; y = b;}
int x;
int y;
}

// x value will not be repeating in a list
Point a1 = new Point(1,2);
Point a2 = new Point(3,5);
Point a3 = new Point(0,2);
Point a4 = new Point(2,7);
Point a5 = new Point(14,2);
Point a6 = new Point(9,10);

SortedList<Point> list = new SortedList<Point>();

list.Add(a1);
list.Add(a2);
list.Add(a3);
list.Add(a4);
list.Add(a5);
list.Add(a6);
```

Is it possible to add all those elements in O(log2n) time? I'd like my list after adding this to look like that. Without being forced to sort it over again after sort.

```
(0,2)
(1,2)
(2,7)
(3,5)
(9,10)
(14,2)
```

And then I'd like to check, wheter there's an object with (x == 9). Would that be possible in O(log2n) time?

Thanks

Comment: I have yet to actually come across a use case where `SortedList` is preferable to some other type of data structure.  Odds are something else is better.  You'd need to describe your use case to say what data structure would be appropriate though.

Comment: Will the x value be unique in your data?

Comment: I've edited my question, hope its OK now

Comment: Can 2 or more points share an x value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
var list = new SortedList<int, Point>
{
    { 1, new Point(1, 2) },
    { 3, new Point(3, 5) },
    { 0, new Point(0, 2) },
    { 2, new Point(2, 7) },
    { 14, new Point(14, 2) },
    { 10, new Point(9, 10) },
}
```

As stated on MSDN, inline object initialization is especially beneficial for SortedLists.

To see if you have point with an x of 3, you would use

```
Point x3Point;
if (list.TryGetValue(3, out x3Point))
{
    //x3Point is now set to the Point with an x value of 3.
}
```

---

Of course you could just store two `int`s

```
var list = new SortedList<int, int>
{
    { 1, 2 },
    { 3, 5 },
    { 0, 2 },
    { 2, 7 },
    { 14, 2 },
    { 10, 10 },
}
```

which you could use like this

```
int yValue;
if (list.TryGetValue(3, out yValue))
{
    var x3Point = new Point(3, yValue);
}
```

---

Ideally you initialise the list with pre sorted data.

Comment: Can't I use new SortedList<int, int> then? If all I want to hold inside this list is 2 ints?

Answer (score 1):

Directly from MSDN:

> Represents a collection of key/value pairs that are sorted by the keys
>   and are accessible by key and by index.

So, of course, it's a List type that is useful if you have to keep its values always sorted by a specific criteria. Have a look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/e7a8xew6.aspx) for further examples and explainations!

Answer (score 1):

You can create [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) via LINQ mapping query. Example is given below. Note that SortedList is basically a sorted hashtable (`SortedList` implements `IDictionary`) with key-value item. So I select equal keys and values from array of ints.

```
var ints = new []{1,54,65,76,34,36};
SortedList sorted =  new SortedList(ints.ToDictionary(key => key, val => val));
```